# How to create android launcher based on Google's Launcher2

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a custom launcher but based on the google's Launcher2, I have the source code of Launcher2 but when I import it to the eclipse I get a bunch of errors. Form what I've searching I think that I need to compile the android source and add it to the eclipse. I have compiled the source already following this [link](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) and then [this](http://pickerwengs.blogspot.pt/2011/02/android-how-to-develop-android-launcher.html), but I get nowhere.
What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Launcher2 application uses framework classes that are not included in the android SDK.  As such you cannot simply copy the Launcher2 application code and build it.  I spent quite a bit of time trying to manually copy over dependent classes, but it simply became too complicated.

Launcher2 is too integrated with the OS to copy over.